# using css3 columns - how can get element position?

Tags: javascript, css

To divide the long html file with the columns, I used css3 columns.

```
padding: 0px
height: 1024px
-webkit-column-gap: 0px
-webkit-column-width: 768px
```

And i wanted to get the position of the specified element, so i used the following javascript code.

```
function getPos(el) {
   for( var lx=0, ly=0; el!=null; lx+=el.offsetLeft, ly+=el.offsetTop, el=el.offsetParent);
         return {x:lx, y:ly};
}
```

I thought that the y value is in range of 0 to height:1024px, but that value exceeds 1024 and x value is in range of 0 to column-width:768.

How can i get the realative position from the first top left position which y is in 0 to 1024 and x is some value?

I'm sorry for my poor english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery method `position` returns the correct answer for this. Is it possible for you to include jQuery?

See http://jsfiddle.net/chris5marsh/GM2kp/ for an example.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain more details? I've never used jquery before, so i'm a such mess.

Comment: I wouldn't use jQuery just to perform this task. jQuery is a Javascript library that smoothes over a lot of cross-browser differences and makes it easier to code complex Javascript. Head to http://jquery.com for instructions on how to install and use it.